# can we modifiy the transaction record in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a transacton called **updatewarranty**.In that  **updatewarranty** transaction i am updating a asset called warranty.
This is my json

```
{
"$class": "org.network.warranty.Transfer",
"TransferId": "9427",
"AuthKey": "",
"TransferDate": "2018-06-30T05:50:32.767Z",
"customer": {
"$class": "org.network.warranty.Customer",
"CustomerId": "2599",
"Address1": "",
"Address2": "",
"Authkey": "",
"City": "",
"Country": "",
"Email": "",
"Mobile": "",
"State": "",
"UserType": 0
 },
"retailer": {
"$class": "org.network.warranty.Retailer",
"RetailerId": "8389",
"Address1": "",
"Address2": "",
"Authkey": "",
"City": "",
"Country": "",
"Email": "",
"Mobile": "",
"State": "",
"UserType": 0
 },
 "warranty": {
 "$class": "org.network.warranty.Warranty",
 "WarrentyId": "0766",
 "End_Date": "2018-06-30T05:50:32.767Z",
 "Start_Date": "2018-06-30T05:50:32.767Z",
 "IS_Internationaly_Valid": "",
 "Item_QRCode": ""
 }
 }
```

I have a transaction named **getwarranty** which takes the warranty id as input.
this is my json

```
{
"$class": "org.network.warranty.getWarranty",
"warranty": "resource:org.network.warranty.Warranty#0766"
}
```

When i see the transaction record for getwarranty i dont have the entire transfer record. I have only this information

```
{
"$class": "org.network.warranty.getWarranty",
"warranty": "resource:org.network.warranty.Warranty#0766",
"transactionId": "6e35c9cb-d3a6-41d8-8c95-fa22c7681824",
"timestamp": "2018-06-30T05:50:54.851Z"
 }
```

how can i get the warranty asset?

Comment: 1) you can define a query to query `updatewarranty` (although your JSON suggests its called `Transfer`) as a transaction class and use a WHERE clause for `WarrantyId` - you can call it as a REST API endpoint - you need to start an instance of Composer REST server for that. .

Comment: the above is the transaction record, as a query. 2) If need be, you can additionally write a query on the asset class `"org.network.warranty.Warranty"` - pass it a parameter of `WarrantyId` and also call it direct, as a REST API endpoint (query endpoint) You would see all of the data that's registered/updated for that particular WarrantyID -> see queries tutorial for reference info https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries